# how can sum 2 select results in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

hi i want sum two results from other select

i try some way but i cant find any ways please help me
here is my code

```
SELECT
name1,count1,count2FROM
(
    SELECT
        trade.name AS name1, COUNT(workorders.id) AS count1
    FROM      workorders
    RIGHT JOIN    trade
    ON trade.id = workorders.trade_id 
    AND     workorders.hcworkorderstat_id IN (
            SELECT     hcworkorderstat.id
            FROM       hcworkorderstat
            WHERE hcworkorderstat.code NOT IN ( 'CL','CANCEL' ))
    GROUP BY  trade.name
) tab1LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT
        trade.name AS name2,
        COUNT(workorders.id) AS count2
    FROM
        workorders
    RIGHT JOIN
        trade
    ON
        workorders.trade_id = trade.id
    AND
        workorders.requesteddate BETWEEN '1391.01.15' AND '1396.10.15'
    GROUP BY
        trade.name
) tab2
ON tab1.name1=tab2.name2
```

need results count1+count2 also i need show count 1 and count 2 in table
how can do that?

Comment: And your question is ????

Comment: @APC  i need sum of count 1 and two also i need show count 1 and count 2 in table

Answer (score 1):

> " i need sum of count 1 and two also i need show count 1 and count 2 in table"

Hmmm, well the only hard about that is the LEFT JOIN means that `count2` will be null when there's no match on `tab1.name1=tab2.name2`. We can't do arithmetic with nulls so you need to default it to zero. Something like this:

```
SELECT
   name1, count1, count2, count1 + nvl(count2,0) as tot FROM
(
   ...
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
SELECT name1,count1, count2, (count_1+count_2) AS sum_of_counts
FROM
(
SELECT name1,count1, count2, case when count1>0 then count1 else 0 end as count_1, 
case when count2>0 then count2 else 0 end as count_2
FROM
 (
    SELECT
        trade.name AS name1, COUNT(workorders.id) AS count1
    FROM      workorders
    RIGHT JOIN    trade
    ON trade.id = workorders.trade_id 
    AND     workorders.hcworkorderstat_id IN (
            SELECT     hcworkorderstat.id
            FROM       hcworkorderstat
            WHERE hcworkorderstat.code NOT IN ( 'CL','CANCEL' ))
    GROUP BY  trade.name
 ) tab1
LEFT JOIN
 (
    SELECT
        trade.name AS name2,
        COUNT(workorders.id) AS count2
    FROM
        workorders
    RIGHT JOIN
        trade
    ON
        workorders.trade_id = trade.id
    AND
        workorders.requesteddate BETWEEN '1391.01.15' AND '1396.10.15'
    GROUP BY
        trade.name
 ) tab2
ON tab1.name1=tab2.name2
) a;
```

Comment: hi. i need show count 1 and count 2 and sum of tow in table

Comment: That was not clear in the question. I thought you only wanted sum with name

Comment: sorry my bad so you know any way?

Comment: yup there's always a way. Give me 2-3 minutes

Comment: I have updated the query. Not sure whether this will work or not. Try it and let me know

Comment: You are welcome. Happy to help. You can accept and like my answer if that was helpful. Visit this link to know more about it http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: What's the deal with "Using Union all"?